# Best way to Load other asp.net web pages in Ajax Modal Popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I need to load Comment.aspx (Web Form) page in Ajax Modal popup which is defined MainPage.aspx

What is the best way to do it

MainPage.aspx

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowEmailArticlePopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnEmail" PopupControlID="pnlEmailArticle"
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" RepositionMode="None"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticle" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="500px" Width="520px" >

<div id="emailArticle" class="commentForm">
 <div id="closeEmailArticle" class="commentClose">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" onclick="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup_Click" 
        CausesValidation="False"  /> </div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlEmailArticle" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

//Need to load the COMMENT PAGE HERE


</asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Comment.aspx** page code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticleForm" runat="server" Visible="true">
 <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td  colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleTitle" runat="server" Text="Article Title Will Go here"  CssClass="lblPostComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleRequired" CssClass="txtLabelComment" runat="server" Text="[*] indicates a required field."></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleFriendsEmail" runat="server" Text="Your friends email address" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailArticleFriendsEmail" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required,custom[email]] txtbox300Comment" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleYourName" runat="server" Text="Your Name" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailArticleYourName" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required] txtbox300Comment" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleYourEmail" runat="server" Text="Your email address" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailArticleYourEmail" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required,custom[email]] txtbox300Comment" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleYourMSG" runat="server" Text="Your Message" CssClass="txtLabelComment" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailArticleYourMSG" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required, maxSize[500]] txtbox300MComment" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  valign="top" >                            
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailArticleVC" runat="server" Text="Verification Code" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" >
                        <uc1:MyCaptcha ID="MyCaptcha2" runat="server"  />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td > &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEmailArticle" runat="server" onclick="btnEmailArticle_Click" 
                                Text="Send Message" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td > &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>  
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="510px">
        <tr>
            <td height="510px" valign="middle" align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Solution**: I used following approach. I am posting this solution also so that other may have choice. 
It fits quite well for my needs

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%= imgBtnClose.ClientID %>").click(function () {

                $('#frmComment').validationEngine('hideAll')

             });

             $("#<%= lnkBtnComment.ClientID %>").click(function () {

             $("#<%=pnlCommentForm.ClientID %>").load("Comment.aspx", function (){});
                 $(".formErrorContent").show();
                 $(".formErrorArrow").show();
             });
});
```

I also have marked one of the answer as correct as that could have been used in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an iframe to show the content of the Comment page in the main page. This way you preserve the styling of the comments page.

```
<iframe src="/comment.aspx" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
```

If you still want to use jQuery then the following will do the task.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="#results"/>
<script>
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "comment.aspx",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To get the comments html appended to your target element use the following in the ajax success function.

```
$('#<%=updPnlEmailArticle.ClientID%>').append(html);
```

Just one other thing. You should use the AssociatedControlID of the Label control in you comment form. This makes the label render as an [HTML label tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) which is a simple usability improvement.

Hope this helps.

Keith

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I used a different approach for my requirement.  My solution works for me quite well         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= imgBtnClose.ClientID %>").click(function () {

                $('#frmComment').validationEngine('hideAll')
    
             });

             $("#<%= lnkBtnComment.ClientID %>").click(function () {

             $("#<%=pnlCommentForm.ClientID %>").load("Comment.aspx", function (){});
                 $(".formErrorContent").show();
                 $(".formErrorArrow").show();
             });
});

Comment: Do comment on what i have used, I load the page only when user click on comment or email link other wise my inline validation get initialized on page load and validation popups for either FORM show up in the other modal popups also, which was frustrating and difficult for me to handle. Thanks

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean, does either solution work for you? You might have get the innerHtml of the asp.net form in comment.aspx and append that to your main page. But, if you need to have two separate forms and you can't extract the content of the comment.aspx page into a UserControl then the iframe is your best solution as it keeps the two page structures from interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user control that both Comment.aspx and MainPage.aspx have.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)